# Matplotlib - Pie Chart from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I saw a sample from the internet to build a simple pie chart from Matplotlib but not sure how to embed it with my dataset (https://gist.github.com/datomnurdin/33961755b306bc67e4121052ae87cfbc).

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

my_labels = 'Positive','Neutral','Negative'
my_colors = ['lightblue','lightsteelblue','silver']
plt.pie(df, labels=my_labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=15, shadow = True, colors=my_colors)
plt.title('Sentiment Overview')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

P.S: The dataset didn't contain any labels, only values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
my_labels = {1:'Positive',0:'Neutral',-1:'Negative'}
my_colors = ['lightblue','lightsteelblue','silver']

# count the values to plot pie chart
s = df.sentiment.map(my_labels).value_counts()

plt.pie(s, labels=s.index, autopct='%1.1f%%', colors=my_colors)
# also
# s.plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%', colors=my_colors)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]